# ARC and releasing memory in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.predictionsObjectArray = [[AAPredictions alloc] init];

    [self.predictionsObjectArray setPredictionsArray:@[@"Probably Not", @"Ask Again", @"I doubt it", @"Unlikely", @"I believe so"]];



    for (int x = 1; x<61; x++) {
        NSMutableString *imageName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        if (x > 9) {
            imageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"CB000%i.png", x];
        }
        else {
           imageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"CB0000%i.png", x];
        }

        [self.animationImagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];

    }

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark Prediction

-(void)makePrediction {
    self.predictionLabel.text = [self.predictionsObjectArray getPrediction];
    [self animateItems];


}
-(void)animateItems {

    self.image_button.alpha = 0.0;

    self.background_image.animationRepeatCount = 1.0;

    self.background_image.animationImages = self.animationImagesArray;

    self.background_image.animationDuration = 3.0;
    [self.background_image startAnimating];






    while (self.background_image.isAnimating) {

    }

    self.image_button.alpha = 1.0;

}
```

Making a simple crystal Ball app, and am trying to animate it. I have really been working at this for a while with no luck. Hoping someone can help me as I am learning, particularly the ARC.
I know I need to add a line in the `viewDidLoad` function to add the reference count to +1 of `self.animationImagesArray`, because when I goto assign `self.background_image.animationImages` to `self.animationImagesArray`, ARC released it and I know because in the debugger at the bottom, it’s value in nil. Any help would be great.

Comment: Is `animationImagesArray` a `weak` property?

Answer (score 1):

Grady is correct. You never initialized the array. If you don't have an init like he posted (which for someone that is extremely new it maybe confusing) just do this:

```
//NEW: Initialize the array before adding items to it
self.animationImagesArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int x = 1; x<61; x++) {
    NSMutableString *imageName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if (x > 9) {
        imageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"CB000%i.png", x];
    }
    else {
        imageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"CB0000%i.png", x];
    }

    [self.animationImagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

generally what you are trying to do is a bad idea... ARC really has you covered in such a trivial case, your problem is that you don't initialize `self.animationImagesArray` to anything.

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init]
    if (self)
    {
          self.animationImagesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: or animationImagesArray is weak... which the fix should be obvious for.